# PHP: Online Offline Status

Tags: php, mysql

Hi since 3 hour I am trying to make this work but not getting the result as I want. I want to display user list with online and offline status.

Here is the table

[image]

and here what I tried to get status result.

```
$loggedtime = time() - 300; // 5 minutes

$query = 'SELECT userid, handle FROM ^users WHERE loggedin = '.$loggedtime.' ORDER BY userid ASC';

// below are scripts function qa_ pleses refer this http://www.question2answer.org/functions.php

$result = qa_db_query_sub($query);  
$users = qa_db_read_all_assoc($result); 

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if($row['userid'] > $loggedtime){
    echo $row['handle'].' is online';
} else {
    echo $row['handle'].' is offline';
}
```

**NOT THIS TOO**

```
foreach($users as $user){
    if($user['userid'] > $loggedtime){
        echo $user['handle']. ' is online';
    } else {
        echo $row['handle'].' is offline';
    }
}
```

None of above code working. I am new to MYSQL and PHP just know basic so please help me to solve this.

**EDIT:**
I have tried now this but not working

```
foreach($users as $user){
                if($user['loggedin'] > $loggedtime){
                    echo $user['handle']. ' is online';
                } else {
                    echo $row['handle'].' is offline';
                }
            }
```

**EDIT 2**

```
$query = "SELECT
    userid, handle, 
    CASE
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, loggedin, NOW()) < 300
            THEN 'Online'
        ELSE 'Offline'
    END AS 'status'
FROM ^users
ORDER BY userid";

$result = qa_db_query_sub($query); 

while($user = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $user['handle'] . '<BR/>';
}
```

**NEW APPROACH**

Please check this for new approach [User online offline status - offline status issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208172/user-online-offline-status-offline-status-issue)

Comment: Seems kinda whacky and illogical to compare the userid versus the $loggedtime, since they have nothing in common. Fix that and see what happens.

Comment: I have edited updated code can you please check and tel me where I am wrong now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you fixed the user id comparison, let's address the next issue..

You're trying to compare a string DATE versus a unix timestamp. Let's make them the same type and compare:

```
foreach($users as $user)
{
  $user_time = strtotime($user['loggedin']);
  if($user_time > $loggedtime)
  {
    echo $user['handle']. ' is online';
  } else {
    echo $row['handle'].' is offline';
  }
}
```

Overall not the best way to approach this problem, but it might get this working for you. The database solution above is probably best.

Comment: This is not rendering anything..!

Comment: Tested this code on my local machine here manually typing in your datetimes from above.. It works.

Comment: Yeh I can understand but somehow I am not getting it. these query function can cause the issue? `result = qa_db_query_sub($query);  
  $users = qa_db_read_all_assoc($result);`

Comment: Look at your MySQL query... `SELECT userid, handle FROM ^users WHERE loggedin = '.$loggedtime.' ORDER BY userid ASC` This logic says in lamen: "Get me users where their login time is EQUAL TO the current time minus 5 minutes. You will never get a result unless you have a record with the accuracy of 1 second...

Comment: Take out that WHERE clause and see how it works: `SELECT userid, handle FROM ^users ORDER BY userid ASC`

Comment: I have taken out WHERE now it is displaying every user as a logged in user means online user. I think what @jjs9534 said that is correct and now I noticed that issue.

Comment: the point in removing the WHERE is to make sure the remainder of the code executes.. Good Luck.

Comment: Yes it is executing the code with all user in database with showing online status

Answer (score 1):

Why not just check on the database side?

```
SELECT
    userid, handle, 
    CASE
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, loggedin, NOW()) < 300
            THEN 'Online'
        ELSE 'Offline'
    END AS 'status'
FROM ^users
ORDER BY userid
```

> You can use `TIMESTAMPDIFF(unit,datetime_expr1,datetime_expr2)` to return `datetime_expr2 – datetime_expr1`, where `datetime_expr1` and `datetime_expr2` are `date` or `datetime` expressions. One expression may be a `date` and the other a `datetime`; a `date` value is treated as a `datetime` having the time part `'00:00:00'` where necessary. The unit for the result (an integer) is given by the unit argument. The legal values for unit are the same as those listed in the description of the `TIMESTAMPADD()` function.

Take a look at the [MySQL Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Also, I strongly advise using [reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) for table names.

Comment: So if I use this query than do I have to check conditionally in php? or it will done with this query itself? Sorry but this type of code writing very first time

Comment: @pixelngrain See my updated query. If you use this, you do not have to do any checking in PHP.

Comment: Okay let me try and get back to you in a moment

Comment: Please check my Edit 2 I am getting all user regardless the status. I am sorry I am really dumbo in this. please dont get frustrate

Comment: @pixelngrain Are you trying to show the status of users from the last 5 minutes? If yes, then what's the criteria that determines whether they are on **online** or **offline**? You also need to `echo $user[status] . '<BR/>';`

Comment: Can we use session cookie etc? Actually myself confuse now that how to make this happen. :( Any suggestion or guideline?

Comment: @pixelngrain I have no idea how a session cookie comes into this.

Answer (score 1):

Your structure looks funny to answer the question. Your loggedin field actually looks more like a "the last time they logged in". Just because you know when they logged in doesn't necessarily mean they are "online".

The reason your query isn't working is because you are comparing a UNIX timestamp to a mysql datetime. In addition, you are using = so unless they logged in EXACTLY five minutes ago, this will not work.

At minimum.

```
SELECT userid, handle FROM ^users WHERE loggedin > '.date('Y-m-d h:i:s', time()-300).'ORDER BY....
```

Comment: Oh wow.. thanks to notice me.. I 100% agree with you. So now how can I get status?

Comment: This is a much more complicated answer than this post allows, it would require additional fields, session checking, etc....

Comment: Do you mean by creating extra tables?

Comment: Not extra tables necessarily, but probably more robust than you current structure. It all depends on the project.

Comment: Actually I want to display user list where it indicates online and offline status. I am using this open source http://www.question2answer.org. You can read some functions here if may helps http://www.question2answer.org/functions.php

Comment: It doesn't look like any of the functions in that list are going to help you with what you are trying to do. You may want to contact Q2A for support. I haven't personally done any work using them.

Comment: Okay no problem.. Thanks for your help and effort. I appreciate it.