# User online offline status - offline status issue

Tags: php, mysql, status

First this is related question of [PHP: Online Offline Status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201579/php-online-offline-status/13201617#comment17974371_13201617)
But as my approch is little different and issue too so I thought new question would be better.

Now I have added one column to qa_users table called "online" which insert/update logging time  and keep update upon user interaction (i am not sure is it right or not)

Now it is displaying user online as soon as they logged in but issue is after logged out they are keep display status as online and never go offline status.

I think something wrong with my time comparison conditional code but what I don't know.

Please find below code what I am using.

```
$loggedtime = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', time()-300); // 5 minutes

$query = 'SELECT userid, handle, online FROM ^users ORDER BY userid ASC';           
$result = qa_db_query_sub($query);  

while($ids = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $online = $ids['online'];
    $userid = qa_get_logged_in_userid();

    if(qa_is_logged_in()){
        $update = 'UPDATE ^users SET online = NOW() WHERE userid = '.$userid.'';

        qa_db_query_sub($update);
    }

    $time = $ids['online'];

    if ($time >= $loggedtime){ // i have tried with $loggedtime > $time too
        echo '<li>'.$ids['handle'].' online</li>';
    } else {
        echo '<li>'.$ids['handle'].' offline</li>';
    }               

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your DB structur it's kind of a guess.

```
if ($time >= $loggedtime)
```

You are comparing a string like '2012-11-01 10:10:10' with whatever `$time` is in your DB. This seems to be the problem here.
You could/should use UNIX timestamps. They can be compared easily.

If `$time` were a UNIX timestamp you could just do:

```
if ($time >= time()-300)
```

**EDIT:**

Change your query to get a UNIX timestamp for `online`

```
$query = 'SELECT userid, handle, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(online) as online FROM ^users ORDER BY userid ASC';
```

**EDIT2:**
To make it more clear:
In your first version you were comparing two Dates in the form '2012-11-01 10:10:10'

```
if ('2012-11-01 10:10:10' < '2012-11-02 10:10:10')
```

This can't work in PHP - it's like doing:

```
if ('apples' < 'bananas')
```

You have to compare numbers. Therefore i suggested using unix timestamps which can be easily compared.

Comment: Your you are right. Actually I have tried $loggedtime > $time too but none of work..let me try what you adviced

Comment: Now its making every one offline

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time for unix timestamp. All you have to figure out is how to get a unix timestamp from your DB. If you'd provide us with the structure of your table, we can help with the query.

Comment: Maybe you insert a `echo $time` to see, what `$time` is ;)

Comment: yeh let me check with echo... this is the time format I am getting `2012-11-03 14:28:38` I think that may be the reason as format is different. Can be?

Comment: Okay, so you're not getting a unix timestamp for your DB. **see edit**

Comment: No, I am getting it DB time stamp is `2012-11-03 14:32:09` and with php time() function getting this `1351938770`

Comment: Hi,, Can I store time in integer in db?

Answer (score 1):

Let me start with this:

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

---

The approach I used for this sort of thing, is to not only save the logged in status of the user, but to save his **last activity time** as well.

Where activity may mean:

- Vitied a page.
- Submitted a form.
- Did anything on your site

A user is considered logged out if one of the following apply:

- User has logged out via the "Log Out" link.
- User has not been active for N seconds.

To check activity, you compare the last activity time against the current time. If the difference (`$currentTime - $lastActiveTime`) is greater than `N`, you consider the user as logged out.

The list of logged in users would be refreshed every couple of seconds (using a caching mechanism of some sort), where Inactive users would be `UPDATE`d to "Logged Out" in the database, thus saving you some query time and later processing time.

Comment: Actually, this is what he does. He updates the "ONLINE" column. He just got the compare wrong, as i pointed out.

Comment: One thing to clearify. I didn't give you negative vote. Second I was reading to your answer but truly couldn't understand most thing. Either because I am new to MySQL or may be you used expert terms or language.

Comment: @pixelngrain: What didn't you understand? I'll do my best to clarify.

Comment: First about deprecation process. second how i can get activity time. What I mean to say is how to identify user is logged out. I thought by creating and updating time would be most easiest way as it will keep update time on page refresh or reload and php time can keep check either matching or not than if not than status chage.. but don't know why not working

Comment: @pixelngrain: About the "don't use `mysql_*` functions", read the links associated with it, read them thoroughly. `mysql_*` functions are ancient, and shouldn't be used anymore. As for identifying the user's logged in status, Every time the user is doing something on your site, you update the "last activity time" to the current time. Then, when the list is viewed, you only display those who were last active less than (for example) 10 minutes ago. So if I left your site 11 minutes ago, I would be considered offline, because I didn't do anything for a long time.

Comment: Ah! okay.. I need to check in my code. I will surely try what you advice. However my problem has been solve by @bidifx answer but I really thank you too showing me some different way and approach. I will get back to you once will start with what you say. thanks again